# intellij idea community edition + JPA

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea

everyone!

I'm a newbie in working in intellij idea, so I'll ask just short and simple question: Is it possible to use persistance api in community edition of intellij idea.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use JPA in project in community edition, BUT IntelliJ IDEA won't help you use it. I think you will get only basic xml code completion in configuration and mapping files but it's all.